Passivsätze ohne Subjekt mit Dativ
Ich glaube, ich verstehe das Thema von Passivsätzen ohne Subjekt ziemlich gut, aber mir ist folgender Satz eingefallen und ich wollte sicher sein, dass er richtig ist


Die Tatsache ist, dass den Kindern bestimmt von den Lehrern
geholfen werden kann.


Es kommt mir nur ein bisschen komisch vor, dass kann im Singular ist, wenn wir Kindern und Lehrern haben.  Aber wir haben


Den Kindern wird geholfen


also es wurde mir gesagt, dass genauso, wie man im 2. Satz das Singular verwendet, verwendent man das Singular auch beim ersten Satz.

Richtig. Das Dativobjekt beeinflusst nicht die Konjugation. Der Satz hat kein Subjekt und daher ist die Konjugation grundsätzlich dritte Person singular. Das kommt daher, dass es dann nicht seltsam klingt, wenn man den Platzhalter es einfügt.

Es wird den Kindern geholfen.
Es kann den Kindern geholfen werden.


Aber der Platzhalter "es" beeinflusst die Kongruenz doch auch nicht... – Und hier klingt für mich der Satz mit "es" am Anfang recht schräg (weiß nicht warum)

@Alazon: Der Platzhalter "es" ist das (nicht genannte) Subjekt des Relativsatzes und deshalb richtet sich die Konjugation des Verbs nach diesem - selbst dann und obwohl es nicht genannt ist.

Insbesondere ist dass es den Kindern geholfen werden kann extrem schlecht.

@DavidVogt  Der ursprüngliche Satz war ein bisschen anders - komplizierter - aber er hat mit diesem Nebensatz geendet. Es war ein Aufsatz über Lehrer und Kinder.   Inwiefern ist der Satz schlecht?  So was würde man nicht normalerweise schreiben?

@Bakunin: Ein Vorfeld-Expletiv ist kein Subjekt.

@Cerulean Der Nebensatz kann kein es enthalten. Es gibt also kein ausgelassenes Subjekt, sondern der Satz ist wirklich subjektlos. Was Jankas These angeht, daß das expletive oder Vorfeld-es hier eine Rolle spielt: Sätze mit diesem und dem Verb im Plural sind alltäglich. Es folgen einige Beispiele. Es wurden keine Probleme gefunden. Es gelten neue Öffnungszeiten.

Diese Sätze haben aber allesamt ein Subjekt, daher richtet sich die Konjugation auch nach diesem.

Das Argument war: Ohne Subjekt steht das Verb im Singular, da Platzhalter-es und Plural komisch klingen. Platzhalter-es und Plural ist aber ziemlich alltäglich?

Und mein Argument ist, dass die Konjugation ohne Subjekt keinen Anker hat. Also hat irgendwer in finsterer Vergangenheit mal das Platzhalter-es für das Subjekt gehalten und die Konjugation daran festgemacht. Und das ist dann auf alle subjektlosen Fälle ausgedehnt worden, auch wenn gar kein Platzhalter-es da ist.
